# How to use stencilJs web components in Angular Universal

Tags: javascript, angular, web-component, angular-universal, stenciljs

I have developed some web components using stencilJs, and add them to my angular project by npm package with no issue

The changes I made was

main.ts

```
import { applyPolyfills, defineCustomElements } from 'my-package/loader';

...
applyPolyfills().then(() => {
    defineCustomElements();
});
```

and in App.moudle

```
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
```

then in my app.component.html

```html
 <my-comp #comp></my-comp>
```

and in my app.component.ts

```
    @ViewChild('comp') comp!: ElementRef<HTMLMyCompElement>;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log(this.digitalVerification.nativeElement);
        this.comp.nativeElement.configure({ token: '123' });
    }
```

and this is working prefect with no error

Then I tried to convert my app to angular universal to have some server side rendering, by running `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine`

Then in the added files I made these changes

app.server.module.ts

```
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
```

main.server.ts

```
  import { applyPolyfills, defineCustomElements } from 'my-package/loader';

  ...
  applyPolyfills().then(() => {
      defineCustomElements();
  });
```

Then I ran the project by `npm run dev:ssr`, but I get this error in terminal as soon I open the page, although `this.digitalVerification.nativeElement` has value and I am able to see it in terminal logs

> ERROR TypeError: this.comp.nativeElement.configure is not a function

Any idea?

Comment: This is your answer https://stenciljs.com/docs/hydrate-app

Comment: @Milad yes, that documentation is very minimal, do you have a working example?